# Acentos e Caracteres especiais em Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma consulta que é feita com Ajax request via jQuery. 
Nos campos quando digito um caractere como "ç" e envio a requisição para o servidor, está chegando com o caractere em outro formato. 
Ex: Escrevo ç no campo nome e chega na Action dessa forma: Ã§. Estou usando Struts 1.

Código chamada Ajax:

```
var request = $.ajax({
            cache: true,
            url: "/listagem",
            data:{  action: "ajax", 
                    page_num: page_num,
                    categoria: options.categoria,
                    estado: options.estado,
                    cidade: options.cidade,
                    especialidade: options.especialidade,
                    nome: options.nome_prestador,
                    bairro: options.bairro_prestador,
                    area_atuacao: options.area_atuacao,
              }
            });
        request.done(function(data){
            montarHtmlLista(data);
        });
```

Já tentei colocar os seguintes parâmetros e não deu certo:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1",
dataType: "json",
```

Esse outro também:

```
 beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
   xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
 }
```

Meu JSP já possui as seguintes linhas:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="utf-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Comment: Sua aplicação é feita com JAVA?

Comment: Sim é feita, pq?

Comment: Seria legal passar essa informação como tag ... só uma recomendação na sua pergunta

Comment: Vc diz criar uma tag especifica para poder resolver o problema?

Comment: você colocou na tag jquery ajax eu acredito que colocando java também ficaria mais completa sua pergunta, mas, deixo isso você decidir. !!!

Comment: Entendi agora. Achei que vc estava falando da Taglib utilizado no JEE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando for fazer requisições Ajax que possam ter problemas de encoding (por conter acentos, tils, cedilhas, ou caracteres não latinos (i.e.: caracteres japoneses, árabes etc.)), utilize o método [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). Isso escapa os caracteres para algo que o servidor deve ser capaz de entender.

I.e.:

```
encodeURIComponent("ç"); // resulta em "%C3%A7"
encodeURIComponent("açaí"); // resulta em "a%C3%A7a%C3%AD"
```

Para cada string que estiver utilizando que possa conter caracteres especiais, não use a string diretamente, mas sim o retorno de `encodeURIComponent` sobre aquela string.

Comment: Consegui da forma que você falou, e na minha action usei um URLDecoder.decode(). Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Voce precisa mudar o page encoding para ISO-8859-1.

Todo encoding da sua aplicação de chamadas em geral deve ter o mesmo charset.

Recomendo que utilize utf-8 por ser um padrão internacional unicode.

```
pageEncoding="utf-8"
```

ou

```
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: Mudei, mas o problema continuou. Obrigado pela resposta =)