# JSON não aceita acentuação

Tags: php, javascript, json

Amigos, estou com um problema, a string que tem acento nao to conseguindo pegar usando JSON:

```
$imagens = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM texto_index");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)){
      $imagens[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($imagens);
```

por ex: Receituário
vem como null

o array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => RECEITUÁRIOS [2] => MASCULINOS [3] => 1 [4] => #ffffff [5] => 56 [6] => 28 [7] => Direita [8] => cache/1404135032s-receituario-feminino-eco2.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => ÓCULOS [2] => MASCULINOS [3] => 1 [4] => #ffffff [5] => 52 [6] => 20 [7] => esquerda [8] => cache/1404225957262.jpg ) )
```

Comment: [Possível duplicata](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15336/acentos-e-caracteres-especiais-em-ajax-jquery). Não é **exatamente** igual mas soluciona o mesmo problema, só que de outra forma.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto eu acredito não ser por causa da linguagem!

Comment: Além do erro da conversão do json também a fonte influenciava @Furlan?

Comment: @user6026, o termo "linguagem" é diferente do termo "encode/charset". Normalmente, o problema segundo o que apresentou, é relacionado ao tipo de encode/charset dos dados e dos scripts PHP. Então o primeiro passo é configurar o ambiente e os dados para um encode apropriado. O recomendado é UTF-8. Se vc quer mesmo resolver da forma correta, padronize o ambiente. Senão, vc pode resolver com gambiarras usando htmlentities e utf_encode, etc.. Nesse caso só vai piorar o que já está ruim.. rsr vc é quem escolhe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coloque na sua primeira linha do seu código assim:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true)
```

e depois da conexão coloque essa linha

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$imagens = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM texto_index");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)){
  $imagens[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($imagens);
```

***De preferência use por padrão sempre a UTF-8***

Podem se feitas também dessa forma:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

***Exemplo sobre a dúvida notação Json:*** [***Ideone***](https://ideone.com/idQpky)

Comment: @HarryPotter 

[http://www.planow.com.br/eco]

na pagina principal vc pode ver as palavras sem acento

Comment: Eu acho que isso é a fonte do css! eu fiz um exemplo aqui para ver e ta certo!!! da uma olhada na sua CSS agora essa fonte não deve ter acentuação, bom eu acho !!!

Comment: Acabei de comprovar a sua fonte css não tem acentuação, verifique isso agora... ! o json ta certo...

Answer (score 1):

Ao utilizar string no charset ISO-8859-1(latin1), a função json_encode do php apresenta problemas, efetuando o corte do valor após o primeiro caracter acentuado.

Para evitar este problema, antes de efetuar a conversão para json, basta converter a string para UTF-8.

No php, para efetuar esta conversão, basta utilizar a função utf8_encode.

Do mesmo modo, este tipo problema deve ocorrer com outros tipos de codificações de caracteres que não sejam UTF-8. É recomendado portanto sempre utilizar UTF-8, principalmente ao precisar atuar com as funções nativas de PHP que atuam com JSON, tanto json_encode como json_decode.

tente fazer um teste da seguinte forma e veja se resolve o seu problema:

```
<?php 

    $imagens = array();
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM texto_index");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)){
        $imagens['id']   = $row[0];
        $imagens['n1']   = utf8_encode($rom[1]);
        $imagens['n2']   = utf8_encode($rom[2]);
        $imagens['n3']   = $row[3];
        $imagens['cor']  = $row[4];
        $imagens['w']    = $row[5];
        $imagens['h']    = $row[6];
        $imagens['lado'] = $row[7];
        $imagens['link'] = $row[8];
    }
    echo json_encode($imagens);

?>
```

Comment: me retornou isso:

["Array","Array"]

Comment: Você pode dar um print_r($imagens); antes do echo json_encode() e colar aqui o resultado só para eu ver o que ele ta gerando para esse array?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => RECEITUÁRIOS [2] => MASCULINOS [3] => 1 [4] => #ffffff [5] => 56 [6] => 28 [7] => Direita [8] => cache/1404135032s-receituario-feminino-eco2.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => ÓCULOS [2] => MASCULINOS [3] => 1 [4] => #ffffff [5] => 52 [6] => 20 [7] => esquerda [8] => cache/1404225957262.jpg ) )

Comment: @Furlan, por favor, adicione esse tipo de detalhes na **pergunta**.

Comment: Eu entendi agora o que acontece... eu editei o meu post para vc dar uma olhada dando uma sugestão de criar indices para o array imagens e definindo o utf8 para o que realmente é um texto... os indices que eu criei são sugestivos, vc muda de acordo com o que você precisa.... 

Esses indices irão facilitar também o uso do json quando tiver q acessar determinada informação