# Acentuação no JSON

Tags: php, json, acentuação

Estou com problema de acentuação quando printo o JSON. Se eu usar caracteres como ã, õ, ô, ç, aparece uns códigos.
Não sei se influencia, mas a coluna está com Collation "utf8_general_ci".
***pesquisa.php***:

```
 $response = array();

 require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

 $db = new DB_CONNECT();
 $pesq = $_GET['pesq'];
 mysql_set_charset('utf8');

 mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM tabela WHERE titulo LIKE '%".$pesq."%'") or die(mysql_error());


 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $product["preco"] = $row["price"];
    $product["titulo"] = $row["titulo"];
    $product["uf"] = $row["uf"];
    $product["cidade"] = $row["cidade"];

    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}

$response["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Nenhum produto";

echo json_encode($response);
}
```

**Retorno**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23105/json-n%C3%A3o-aceita-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 15):

Em vez de:

```
json_encode($response);
```

Use:

```
json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Ou se quiser não "escapar" as barras também:

```
json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

É bom fazer isso porque o arquivo final fica menor.

Veja também: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/json.constants.php

---

Vamos a uns exemplos:

```
$response = array(
    'a' => 'áéíóú -------- //'
);

echo json_encode($response);
// resultado: {"a":"\u00e1\u00e9\u00ed\u00f3\u00fa -------- \/\/"}

echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// resultado: {"a":"áéíóú -------- \/\/"}

echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// resultado: {"a":"áéíóú -------- //"}
```

Answer (score 6):

Isso não é um problema, está de acordo com a [especificação do JSON](http://json.org/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em JavaScript caracteres especiais podem ser usados com códigos de escape Unicode (até mesmo em nomes de variáveis!) no formato `\uNNNN`, e em JSON funciona da mesma maneira.

A [especificação do formato JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) permite que qualquer caractere seja codificado na forma `\uXXXX`, sendo que `XXXX` são dígitos hexadecimais que correspondem ao [Unicode code point](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) do caractere. Por padrão, `json_encode` faz isso com caracteres multi-byte (como é o caso das letras acentuadas), mas isso pode ser alterado como indicado em outra resposta (usando `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` ou qualquer outra das [inúmeras opções](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)).

Mas isso não é um problema em si, talvez apenas fique "estranho" e difícil de visualizar, se você for acessar o JSON diretamente. Mas quando você fizer o *parsing* deste JSON, os escapes `\uXXXX` serão convertidos para os caracteres corretos.

Comment: Obrigado, @hkotsubo

Answer (score 5):

Esse não é um 'problema' com que se preocupar, pois o `decode` se encarrega de converter a acentuação.

```
$array = array( 'nome' => 'Paição' , 'cidade' => 'São Paulo' );
$array = array_map( 'htmlentities' , $array );

//encode
$json = html_entity_decode( json_encode( $array ) );

//Output: {"nome":"Paição","cidade":"São Paulo"}
echo $json;
```

Exemplo tirado direto da [DOC](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php#112020).

Exemplo online no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/eACgWt).

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução simples seria fazer isso:

```
utf8_encode($texto);
```

Isso faz com que ele converta para utf8 e sua string já fique com acentuação correta.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, estava tendo bastante problemas com isso, até que resolvi dar uma atenção maior para tentar uma solução, até que montei esta pequena classe estática, adicionei nela um método de conversão recursivo de arrays para utf8 que encontrei na internet. Atenção o índice dos arrays NÃO podem conter ACENTOS, já os valores não tem problemas. Talvez haja uma solução mais eficiente, porém foi só com esta que consegui resolver o meu problema. Att

```
class JsonEncodePAcentos{

    #Coverte todo o array para utf8 de forma recursiva.
    private static function utf8_converter($array)
    { #Método obtido no site: http://nazcalabs.com/blog/convert-php-array-to-utf8-recursively/
        array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
            if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
                    $item = utf8_encode($item);
            }
        });

        return $array;
    }


    public static function converter($arrayJson){       
        $arrayJson = self::utf8_converter($arrayJson);      
        $var = json_encode($arrayJson, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        return utf8_decode($var);
    }

}


$array = array('Nome'=>'João da Silva Moreira', 'subArray'=>array('Ação', 'Cão', 'carateresEspeciais'=>'\\"'.'"'));

echo JsonEncodePAcentos::converter($array);


//{"Nome":"João da Silva Moreira","subArray":{"0":"Ação","1":"Cão","carateresEspeciais":"\\\"\""}}
```

Answer (score -6):

Apenas use duas vezes o json_encode

```
json_encode(json_encode($sua_variavel));
```

Ex:

```
var opcoes = JSON.parse(<?= json_encode(json_encode($produto->opcoes)); ?>);
```

Esse exemplo mostra como eu passo o JSON para o JS, assim as opções vão ficar tudo certo, no decode (do JS) os acentos voltam