# JSON em PHP com campos existentes imprimindo como Null, como resolver?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, angularjs, ionic

Tenho um SELECT que não está me retornando alguns campos, como por exemplo "Observações". Na imagem a seguir eu listo o array e veja que está como "Null" o campo observações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu SQL de retorno é este:

```
 <?php


header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include 'database.php';

$num_pedido=$_GET['num_pedido'];


$query="SELECT
   dados_pedido.iddados_pedido,
   dados_pedido.nome,
   dados_pedido.endereco,
   dados_pedido.numero,
   dados_pedido.complemento,
   dados_pedido.bairro,
   dados_pedido.cidade,
   dados_pedido.estado,
   dados_pedido.cod_cliente,
   dados_pedido.outro_endereco_cod,
   dados_pedido.forma_pagamento,
   dados_pedido.troco,
   dados_pedido.frete,
   dados_pedido.valor_pedido,
   dados_pedido.cod_fornecedor,
   dados_pedido.total_pedido,
   dados_pedido.observacoes,
   dados_pedido.status_pedido,
   dados_pedido.data_hora_pedido,
   item_pedidos.iditens_pedido,
   item_pedidos.nome,
   item_pedidos.imagem,
   item_pedidos.preco_un,
   item_pedidos.qtd,
   item_pedidos.cod_fornecedor,
   item_pedidos.iddados_pedido
FROM
   dados_pedido INNER JOIN item_pedidos ON dados_pedido.iddados_pedido = item_pedidos.iddados_pedido AND dados_pedido.cod_fornecedor = item_pedidos.cod_fornecedor
WHERE 
   dados_pedido.iddados_pedido='$num_pedido'";


$result=$con->query($query);

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $count=0;
    echo "[";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
            $count++;
            echo json_encode($row);

            if($count!=$row_cnt)
            {
                    echo ",";
            }


    }
    echo "]";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

O SQL, quando rodado sem a condição, me mostra TODOS OS campos:

[image: RESULTADO SEM A CLÁUSURA WHERE]

O que estou fazendo de errado aqui? Como fazer aparecer o campo "Observacoes"no meu retorno?

Comment: Tentei mudar meu JSON assim:

Comment: $resultarray = array();

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
       $resultarray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($resultarray);
}
mysqli_close($con);

Comment: Mas ficou pior....

Comment: Se, por acaso, no banco esses campos setados com null, forem um texto que há acentos e/ou caracteres especiais, deve tratá-los, escapando ou formatando seu encoding

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino Tem alguma dica de como formatar este encoding?

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino realmente é o acento, retirei direto no banco de dados e apareceu. Não sei como tratar na volta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa está utilizando o mesmo formato, *UTF-8* no banco de dados e logicamente fazer o UPDATE/INSERT utilizando a mesma *formatação*.

Para isso primeiro utilize, por exemplo, **faça backup antes**:

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela`
 COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
   CONVERT TO CHARSET utf8mb4;
```

Isso fará utilizar o  *UTF-8*.

Depois, no PHP, *por razões obvias* seria ideal também utilizar o mesmo *CHARSET*:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conexao, 'utf8mb4');
```

---

Agora basta utilizar o `json_encode` com o `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` como indicado [nesta postagem.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65867/acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-json)

```
json_encode($fetch, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

---

Se você usa o *driver* de [Mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqlnd.php) você pode usar o [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) e dispensará o uso do `while`:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include 'database.php';
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$num_pedido = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['num_pedido']); 

$query = "SELECT dados_pedido.iddados_pedido, dados_pedido.nome, dados_pedido.endereco, dados_pedido.numero, dados_pedido.complemento, dados_pedido.bairro, dados_pedido.cidade, dados_pedido.estado, dados_pedido.cod_cliente, dados_pedido.outro_endereco_cod, dados_pedido.forma_pagamento, dados_pedido.troco, dados_pedido.frete, dados_pedido.valor_pedido, dados_pedido.cod_fornecedor, dados_pedido.total_pedido, dados_pedido.observacoes, dados_pedido.status_pedido, dados_pedido.data_hora_pedido, item_pedidos.iditens_pedido, item_pedidos.nome, item_pedidos.imagem, item_pedidos.preco_un, item_pedidos.qtd, item_pedidos.cod_fornecedor, item_pedidos.iddados_pedido FROM dados_pedido INNER JOIN item_pedidos ON dados_pedido.iddados_pedido = item_pedidos.iddados_pedido AND dados_pedido.cod_fornecedor = item_pedidos.cod_fornecedor WHERE dados_pedido.iddados_pedido='$num_pedido'";
$queryExecutada = $con->query($query);

$resposta = $queryExecutada->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($resposta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

*Isso vai fazer a mesma coisa, com muito menos código, utilizando o `real_escape_string` e também o `mysqli_fetch_all`. "Minifiquei" a query do SQL apenas para não "enfatiza-lo", afinal ele permanece igual!*

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolvido! William Obrigado também! Vocês são o máximo!

Comment: @Inkeliz, bem vindo! Se a resposta está correta, coloque-a como concluída.